# Recursion not terminating even though the base cases are perfect

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

I've been trying [this](http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/edit-distance/0/?ref=self) problem. My idea is to try all the possible combinations and if it works then I would proceed with memoization. But actually the recursion is not stopping. This is my algorithm.

This is the code that I've wrote:

```
def min_edits(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) == 0 and len(s2) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0:
        return float("inf")
    elif s1[0] == s2[0]:
        return 1 + min_edits(s1[1:], s2[1:])
    else:
        replace = min_edits(s2[0] + s1[1:], s2)  # Replace the first character of first string with that of second one
        insert = min_edits(s2[0] + s1, s2)  # Adds the first character of second string to first one
        delete = min_edits(s2[1:], s2)  # delete first character of first string
        return min(
            insert,
            replace,
            delete
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc = int(input())
    for i_tc in range(tc):
        input()
        (s1, s2) = input().split(" ")
        answer = min_edits(s1, s2)
        print(answer)
```

This is the recursion tree :

In that recursion tree first branch is replace and second one is insert and the last branch is delete

An "_" indicates that only one string is empty and the function returns infinity.

So we can clearly see that the tree is getting terminated at all cases.

But still it's saying maximum recursion depth exceeded.

Please tell me where I'm doing wrong. Thank you :)

[image: Recursion tree]

Comment: 1) for `len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0`, why return infinity instead of the length of any non-empty words? 2) for `s1[0] == s2[0]`, why add 1 to the return value if the first characters are the same?

Comment: For example if the two strings that came into the function are "b" and "b" then according to the algorithm the next level would be two empty strings. So in the previous step itself they were converted so I'm returning 1

Comment: If only one of them is an empty string then it means that it cannot proceed any further. Even if it goes further it causes infinite never ending loop. So I'm returning infinity there

Comment: Looks like it does terminate, but it can take a very long time.  If you're getting "stack exceeded" errors, it's probably because you were passed a long string.  Python stack limits are a bit small and a recursive implementation is not really appropriate for this problem.

Comment: 1) Each call should not be doing the work of the previous call up the recursion hierarchy, so you should not be adding 1 when they are the same. 2) If only one of them is an empty string, why can't it proceed? Just add or remove the number of letters in the non-empty string, or return zero if both are empty.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I've not tried in geeks for geeks portal. I'm getting recursion depth error for these two strings geek and gesk

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Yes you are correct. I can go further. In your second point you mentioned that return 0 if both of them are empty. So even if they go any further it is of no use. Ultimately it's going to return 0 and that I don't need since this is not a minimum path and this zero might interfere in that min(replace,insert,delete) function

Comment: So I'm returning infinity there itself without letting to go further

Comment: oh... your delete case says `delete = min_edits(s2[1:], s2)` but it should say `delete = min_edits(s1[1:], s2)`

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaat !! That stupid typo. It caused this entire mess. Thanks a lot man

Comment: @MattTimmermans Now it's working fine. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the length of the parameters is not decreasing at every step, which is crucial for the recursive calls to reach the base case. In replace, the length of the both strings stays the same, and in the insert step, the length of one string actually increases.

So, what do we mean by replace, remove or insert? For example, say we have the strings:

```
ABCD and DECD
```

Then if we are looking at index 0, then the replace/remove call would leave us with BCD & ECD, and insert would leave us with either ABCD & ECD, or BCD & DECD. With this approach, the length of at least one string always decreases, so we are guaranteed to reach the base case.

EDIT: The base case *was* being reached, but there was an issue with the logic, so I've added my approach to the problem:

```
def min_edits(s1, s2):
if len(s1) == 0:
    return len(s2)
if len(s2) == 0:
    return len(s1)
elif s1[0] == s2[0]:
    return min_edits(s1[1:], s2[1:]) #characters match, no additional cost here
else:
    replace = min_edits(s1[1:], s2) + 1  # Insert into second string
    insert = min_edits(s1, s2[1:]) + 1  # Insert into first string
    delete = min_edits(s1[1:], s2[1:]) + 1  # replace/remove from both strings
    return min(
        insert,
        replace,
        delete
    )
```

Comment: In that recursion tree you can see that what ever is the path followed one string would definitely become empty and infinity would be returned. In the replace case both of the strings will be sliced from the next index. So it reaches the base case

Comment: It will be sliced in the next index *in the delete recursive call*, not in the insert or replace calls. Consider what happens in the path that makes only replace recursive calls. It will never reach the base case.

Comment: No it's reaching the base case. It's just a typo. :)

Comment: I really liked your method of adding +1 to method calls. In fact I'm getting wrong answer before this and now I'm getting correct answer. You have deleted your approach. It's nice. Please keep it again

Comment: Your method of adding +1 to method call gave me a new intuition so I marked this as answer. Thank you

Comment: I'll put it back up: didn't know if it was too much to add the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem for you non-termination of recursion is a typo I guess.

In the last else part, 'delete = min_edits(s2[1:], s2)' code should be 'delete = min_edits(s1[1:], s2)'. because we are deleting the first character of the first string and remaining stays.

Following code terminated for me properly.

```
else:
    replace = min_edits(s2[0] + s1[1:], s2)  # Replace the first character of first string with that of second one
    insert = min_edits(s2[0] + s1, s2)  # Adds the first character of second string to first one
    delete = min_edits(s1[1:], s2)  # delete first character of first string
    return min(
        insert,
        replace,
        delete
    )
```

But the calculation of the edit cost is not proper. You may want to move it to the place actually you are doing the edit action. Some thing like below.

```
else:
    replace = min_edits(s1[1:], s2[1:]) + 1  # If a replace operation is performed, then s1[0] == s2[0].  As, they have matched reduce the problem to match new strings s1[1:], s2[1:]
    insert = min_edits(s1, s2[1:]) + 1  # If an insert operation is performed @ s1, then s1[0] == s2[0]. As, they have matched reduce the problem to match new strings s1,s2[1:]
    delete = min_edits(s1[1:], s2) + 1  # If an insert operation is performed @ s1. Reduce the problem to match new strings s1[1:], s2

    return min(
        insert,
        replace,
        delete
    )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's reducing...I've played very well with it. I haven't got recursion depth(stackoverflow error) any time !!

Comment: @bharath the code 'replace = min_edits(s2[0] + s1[1:], s2)'  and 'insert = min_edits(s2[0] + s1, s2)' are definitely not reducing the problem size @ current recursive call. This is important property for a DP 'optimal substructure'.

Comment: It reaches base case man. Look carefully. After passing the two strings they are evaluated in the beginning of function. If they are identical at beginning they will be sliced

Comment: @bharath you are right. I overlooked it. I found the root cause for you non-termination of recursion. I have updated it in answer.